# How do we get the number of bytes that a python int occupies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, size, sizeof

I am not looking for a constant recording the maximum value representable with an `int`; I am looking to find out the maximum amount of memory that an `int` can occupy. Consider the following code:

```
import sys

def print_and_execute(*args):
    for s in args:
        print(s, end = " == ")
        r = eval(s)
        print(r)
    return

print_and_execute("type(5) ")     
print_and_execute("sys.getsizeof(5)")    
i = int()    
print_and_execute("i")    
print_and_execute("sys.getsizeof(i)")    
i = 2937    
print_and_execute("i")    
print_and_execute("sys.getsizeof(i)")
print_and_execute("sys.maxsize")
print_and_execute("sys.getsizeof(sys.maxsize)")
```

For my particular machine, the output is:

```
type(5)  == <class 'int'>
sys.getsizeof(5) == 28
i == 0
sys.getsizeof(i) == 24
i == 2937
sys.getsizeof(i) == 28
sys.maxsize == 9223372036854775807
sys.getsizeof(sys.maxsize) == 36
```

Apparently, some `int`s are 24 bytes long, others are 28, still others use 36. How many bytes are required to hold an `int` of any size?

Comment: Python integers can expanded to be as large as necessary. In other words, the upper limit is determined by how much memory is available.

Comment: "some ints are 24 bytes long" - Which one(s) besides 0?

Answer (score 2):

> How many bytes are required to hold any size `int`?

As many as are required. There's no limit on the size of `int`s, they are of arbitrary size as [their documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) states.<sup>*</sup>

[`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) does not represent the maximum size of `int` objects. It is the maximum value of a `Py_ssize_t` which is used (in CPython) for holding values of indexes.

For example, just create a larger `int` than `maxsize` :

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(sys.maxsize * sys.maxsize)
44
```

So, you get the number of bytes for a given `int` by using `getsizeof` on it.

<sup>*Bound, *eventually*, by available memory.</sup>